# Current without potential difference, in the given circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, voltage

[image: Circuit Diagram]

In the given circuit, the value of current comes out to be 0.5 A 
Now if I calculate potential difference between point A and B i.e.
$$V_B + 3i-1.5=V_A$$
On putting value of $i=0.5A$ we get,
$$V_A-V_B=0$$

Means potential difference across point A and B is zero, but still a current is flowing (in the circuit) thought it! How?!

Please explain.

Comment: @jim Apply Kirchhoff's Law for the circuit, $3i + (1)i - 2 + 3i -1.5 =0$ (taking voltage drop as positive and gain as negative) form this equation value of current comes out to be 0.5 A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no revelation here. All you have established is the voltage drop across the 3 Ohm resistor equals the voltage rise across the 1.5 volt battery. You get the same result if you start at A and go to B through the 3 Ohm and 1 Ohm resistor and 2 volt battery.

In any case, a potential difference is not required for current to flow. There are no potential differences across the interconnecting wires where zero resistance is assumed, yet the current is flowing through them. Superconductors carry current with no potential difference. So clearly a potential difference is not required for current to flow.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> potential difference across point A and B is zero, but still a current is flowing (in the circuit) thought it! How?!

Clearly the battery is providing the necessary EMF for the current.

The idea that there must be a potential difference for current is incorrect. Even the idea that current always flows from higher potential to lower potential is incorrect. Those ideas come from Ohm’s law and are only valid in resistors. They are violated in inductors, capacitors, ideal wires, and batteries as well as in more complicated circuits. Not all materials are resistors.